# ASP.Net - Set a System.Drawing.Image to a System.Control.Image

Tags: c#, asp.net, system.drawing

I need to save a Image i create from a byte[] into a Image control in ASPX page. So far:

```
byte[] myByte = (byte[])row["image"];
MemoryStream myStream = new MemoryStream(myByte, false);
System.Drawing.Image sampleImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(myStream);
```

Then I need to set this image into a System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image

How can I do this in the same aspx page, without any external .ashx or .asmx file ?
Basically what i need is to set a byte[] coming from db into a Image Control

Comment: You can try to use base64 encoded images, but usually those should be avoided (performance - you would be unable to cache those); why can't you use external handler/page to serve those ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to setup embedded base64 encoded image (provided the image is png):

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="foo" />

foo.Attributes["src"] = "data:image/png;base64," + 
    Convert.ToBase64String(myByte);
```

Again - this should be avoided; you can't cache images served like this; so if you really really want to serve images from db you should consider external handler/page to serve them (and set up caching on that handler).

Comment: Hi Ondrej, Thank you for your reply ! Noted your point to have a separate .ashx when retrieving images from DB !

Comment: asp:Image doesn't support attributes["src"] only ImageUrl.